# How to view everything running on the event thread

Tags: java, swing, debugging, awt, event-dispatch-thread

We are experiencing a bug we cannot track down where something is freezing up our swing thread (it's been almost 2 weeks now and no real results) - we are experienced Swing programmers but we have a huge program and believe it to be in some of the legacy code

I am wondering, is there any way outside of editing the actual `EventQueue` class in the JDK which will allow us to view all pieces of our code currently running on the Event Dispatch Thread - maybe some type of tool which will allow us to view things as they enter or leave the event dispatch thread?

Comment: have you tried dumping the stack of the java program when it freezes?  http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/Stacktrace/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One interesting approach is to extend [`EventQueue`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html) and `push()` it, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158409).

Comment: Excellent. Sadly, the problem often revolves around something that's _not_ posted to the `EventQueue` when it should be, but the approach may suggest new leads.

Answer (score 4):

Logging everything that passes through the Event Dispatch Thread seems a cumbersome way to diagnose a freeze. Wouldn't it be easier to wait until the problem occurs, and then ask the Event Dispatch Thread what it's doing *now*? One way to do this is to [enable JMX monitoring](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html), connect to your running process with a JMX client such a [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/) (which ships with the JDK), wait for the problem to occur, and then [take a thread dump](http://visualvm.java.net/threads.html).

In case you still wish to log everything the Event Dispatch Thread is doing, you can do this by:

1. In Eclipse, launch the application in debug mode.
2. Create a breakpoint on `EventQueue.dispatchEvent`, right-click it, select "properties", check "condition", and enter the following "condition":

   ```
   System.out.println(arg0);
   return false;
   ```

Answer (score 2):

It might be good idea to try [BTrace](http://kenai.com/projects/btrace) to instrument the EventQueue and capture stack traces each time something gets added. I think the latest VisualVM has plugins that will allow you to instrument a running JVM with a BTrace script.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Oracle JRE, there is a [TracedEventQueue](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/sun/awt/TracedEventQueue.html) included already. You can install it as mentioned before:

```
EventQueue eventQueue = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue();
eventQueue.push(new TracedEventQueue());
```

Note, this will output a **lot** of output...