# Blank popup menus and combo boxes

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I'm seeing a really strange issue with JPopupMenu's and JComboBox's. When the application is under heavy load, there are times when our popup menus appear with the right size and position, but just as blank, grey boxes.

The other issue we think is related is that sometimes, we see stanards JComboBox's appear as though they have no items in them (i.e., they don't pull down). We've seen this issue when the application is not under load. They're not making database calls, or anything like that to populate the combo box items - they use hard-coded items.

I've put the popup menu creation in a SwingUtils.invokelater call, and that helped, but did not make the problem completely go away. I don't know what I would do to change the combo box's behavior. If we just right-click again, the context menu will reappear - fully populated. To get the combo boxes working right again, we just close the dialog that contains them, and then just open it back up.

We're using Java 1.6.17 in a standard desktop app. Is there a bug I don't know about, or something else that would solve it, or at least help us know what else might be going on?

Comment: Hi. Sounds like a very interesting problem. Can you please post an SSCCE that would present the issue. I would like to see under what circumstances this behaviour can occur. I have never experienced this kind of issues, and I would like to see them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*All* GUI components should be constructed "[on the event dispatch thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)," and access to any data owned by another thread must be correctly synchronized. There's a nice summary under [*Memory Consistency Properties*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#package_description).

Addendum: @Boro raises two compelling points related to this problem.

> I have never experienced this kind of issue, and I would like to see one.

The intermittent nature of the problem only *suggests* incorrect synchronization, but proof to the contrary is [difficult](http://www.usingcsp.com/cspbook.pdf). The affected system is likely too large to correct by inspection; sadly, an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) would be contrived and obviously incorrect.

> There might be something else in the code as well, since `invokeLater()` didn't help completely.

One common scenario is a `ListModel` that is constructed lazily, perhaps on another thread. One approach is to log the `EventQueue` and look for anomalies, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158409).

Comment: @trashgod +1 Nice comment with interesting links. I think this must be at least a significant part of the problem. Other, there might be something else in the code as well, since invokeLater didn't help completly?

Comment: Yes, very good comments. I wish I could provide an sscce. If I could, I'd be half-way to solving the problem! If it's helpful, the context menu problem is seen in custom popup menus off of a JTree. At least one of the combo box problems occurs in a dialog that is not "created and shown" on the EDT. I'm searching for other instances like that and I think that's fixable. It's the context menu that's got me baffled for sure.

Comment: Indeed, `JTree` is one of the more EDT sensitive components. Also consider [setComponentPopupMenu()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html), if you don't need an explicit `MouseListener` otherwise.

Comment: Sigh. Okay, so I didn't completely solve it, but it is better after putting our popup calls in the EDT (I didn't get to try setComponentPopupMenu). We're just too far down the road to make any drastic changes in our code. Lesson learned: insist on a good software architect and architecture before you hack everything together. Thanks for your help and suggestions!

Comment: @Dopyiii: Emapthy. [`EventQueue.isDispatchThread()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html#isDispatchThread%28%29) may come handy going forward.