# In Java, Can I have a routine called every time the event-dispatch-thread returns from handling an input event?

Tags: java, events, event-dispatch-thread

I am working on a GUI, and I have a routine to update the display when things change underneath:

```
void update() {
    if (needsUpdating) {
        // ...
        needsUpdating = false;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to avoid calling update() "too often" -- ie, if many properties are set in succession I'd rather update() be called just once.

Is it possible to have update() called after every user input event -- key/mouse/etc? I could do this manually, but I have so many event handlers and I know I'll forget -- can Java do this for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can globally listen to user-events, though I wouldn't recommend it, except if you don't find another way:

http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/08/30/global-event-listeners/

The real problem seems to be your application design:

> I could do this manually, but I have
>   so many event handlers and I know I'll
>   forget

try to *model* those "many" into separate parts and clearly define which part need to trigger an update at which time. Actually, there's no way around such a model, whatever the implementation of the actual listening, once you are beyond the most trivial of applications. For starters, see f.i.

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/71022/what-is-good-programming-practice-for-structuring-java-project

Comment: You're probably right.

The way I was thinking, the actual not-implementation condition I am looking for is "user did something", and I was hoping not to duplicate the condition "user did something" if it already existed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own event queue, by subclassing [EventQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html). With it control all the events, and do your updates when you want. See [How to replace the AWT EventQueue with own implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158254/how-to-replace-the-awt-eventqueue-with-own-implementation).

But I don't understand your use case : swing makes gui updates for all events, why do you want do your own ?

Comment: -1 for calling the cavalry ;-) Much to heavy-weight with desastrous side-effects if done wrong

Comment: You right, but it depends on use case. If Owen is a beginner, you're rigth in all cases :-)