# Eclipse & Java: Is there an event monitoring feature?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, user-interface

When developing java guis (e.g. swing) in eclipse, is there a built-in feature (or plugin) that allows one to monitor all the events that are fired?

Comment: From a *coding perspective*, [EventQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html) was the closest I could find with an [example here](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/09/06/global-event-dispatching/) (See Howard's answer though).

Comment: See also this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158254/how-to-replace-the-awt-eventqueue-with-own-implementation/3158409#3158409) that shows how to instrument the event queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also write an `AWTEventListener` on your own. Just add the following lines to your program.

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(new AWTEventListener() {
    public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent event) {
        System.out.println(event);
    }
}, -1);
```

Replace the output with anything you like. You can also listen to particular events only by changing `-1` to some constants from `AWTEvent`.

Answer (score 1):

There is something in eclipse, im not sure if this is exactly what your looking for. its called a "Watch" it watch for anything that happens with that particular variable.