# What happened to SwingEventMonitor?

Tags: java, swing

I'm working on a possibility to zoom into a UI. Therefore I can't access the components directly and have to catch the events on glasspane.

This works fine as long as I don't use auto-updating-components as JTextArea. Since this is an exam I can't use an external library for zooming.

The caret updating is my actual problem, so I'm looking for an option to get all events without having to attach a listener to the component.

There existed a  [SwingEventMonitor](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2se/javase/technologies/accessibility/docs/jaccess-1.3/doc/api/com/sun/java/accessibility/util/SwingEventMonitor.html) but I can't find it in Java6 anymore. Is the class just renamed? I can add AWTListener via Toolkit.getToolkit().. but since CaretEvent is a SwingEvent it seems like I can't cantch it this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not as convenient, but you can intercept *all* [`AWTEvent`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/AWTEvent.html) subclasses entering the [`EventQueue`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html) by pushing your own queue, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158254/how-to-replace-the-awt-eventqueue-with-own-implementation/3158409#3158409).

Comment: with notice that, all waitng events in EventQueueu should be removed and replaced with action(s) from this brutteForce +1

Comment: @mKrbel: Yes, brute force, but comprehensive. I struggled with the wording; does this read better?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [SwingWorker](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) instead. Here is an [example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/SwingworkerExample.htm).