# How can I tell if my JComponent is receiving repaint calls from software?

Tags: java, swing, awt, repaint, eventqueue

I am trying to narrow down why my JComponent is not redrawing. It is odd in that I can get redraw to work on mouse press and release, but not on drag. Is there a way to print out the EventQueue or verify that the PaintEvent was carried out or dumped? Let me know, thanks.

Comment: Can you give us a reduced version of your code that provokes your problem? Ideally, a version that we could compile and run locally.

Comment: You've likely got a bug in your code. I agree with irfy's recommendation above to show us your code. I've done println's from within the paintComponent method, which sometimes can help, but hopefully you've got no program logic within your paint or paintComponent method, and so I think you're better off debugging the other methods.

Comment: You can always push you own EventQueue that overrides the dispatchEvent method and does Syserr to the console of the event class, source, etc...

Comment: See this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3158409/230513).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to print out jobs on the EventQueue, at least not that I know of.

Are you sure you are calling repaint()? Please note that calling repaint does not guarentee that your component will be repainted immediately or in any timely manner.

My guess is that if you are calling repaint, the problem may be that you are never letting go of the UI thread. If you are waiting on the GUI thread and not releasing, your GUI will never refresh

Answer (score 1):

You can add logging to your application. Consider using [LogBack](http://logback.qos.ch/)

Interesting discussion here about [logging for Swing applications](http://netbeans.dzone.com/news/which-logging-facility-swing) as well.