# How to report AWT/Swing event queue length programmatically?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, event-handling, awt

Ideally, the answer will be platform independent, but platform specific, particularly Oracle JVMs, are useful as well. The project that I'm working on is still running a version 6 JVM.

The particular need has to do with a GUI that is "freezing" from time to time. I'm well aware of doing on GUI work on the EDT. The program was working well on Windows, but after moving to Linux, these "strange" GUI issues began to happen. Actually, this issue has occurred on two applications, both after a Windows to Linux move. JVisualVM shows over 10 million `java.awt.EventQueueItem` objects. The suspicion is that the AWT queue is growing faster than it's being served on Linux, so the idea is to put an AWT queue length indicator on the app and see what it shows as the queue grows/shrinks.

A bit of Googling found [this](https://www.java.net//node/694232), but it does a linear scan of the queue. Maybe there's some better way?

Comment: To explore, you can intercept events, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3158254/230513).

Comment: Ten _million_! `setCoalesce(false)`?

Comment: Nope. Already thought of that and scanned for it. Not turning off the coalesce logic.

Answer (score 3):

Interesting subject. I've investigated the `EventQueue` code a bit, and while I haven't solved your problem, I may have some useful pointers:

1. Oracle's implementation of `EventQueue` doesn't keep a size variable, so unless you take over complete control of the `EventQueue` (see 3), there's no way you're going to do better than a linear scan of the queue when using Oracle's JRE.
2. You can write you're own `EventQueue` (probably copy-pasting Oracle's implementation plus some tweaking** will be the easiest) and use `EventQueue.push(EventQueue)` to install your own implementation. All events in the queue will be transferred to your queue, so you can count them as they are posted to your queue. Unfortunately, this is still a linear scan, but at least now it's platform independent.
3. Alternatively, you could install your own `EventQueue` implementation (see 2) as soon as possible after the original event queue has been created (do this in a static code block at the start of the class that contains your main method). Then, your implementation can count all events as they are posted and you don't have to scan the queue when you want to know the size. You'll just have to hope no one else pushes their own `EventQueue` on top of yours ;)

** Some tweaking: I haven't tried this, but I would strip all public/protected static code (everyone that references those methods/variables uses `java.awt.EventQueue` anyway, and so can you), add the size variable and update this variable in the following four methods: `postEvent(AWTEvent, int)`, `getNextEventPrivate()`, `getNextEvent(int)` and `removeSourceEvent(Object, boolean)`.

A big issue with this modification is the fact that the `EventQueue` makes some calls to AWT methods with default visibility (for example, `Toolkit.getEventQueue()` and `Component.getAccessControlContext()`), which you are not allowed to call since your implementation will be in a different package. You'll have to find a workaround for each case individually.

Comment: "copy-pasting" what is that??, he can extend `EventQueu` and then `push` his own implementation..

Comment: The problem is that you need to modify private methods, which means re-implementing them. Since all code from java.awt.EventQueue calls their 'own' private methods, you also need to re-implement those methods. This chain of re-implementation only stops when you reach public or protected methods. Furthermore, if the chain contains methods with default visibility which are called from elsewhere in java.awt, it becomes impossible to redirect all invocations to the private methods to your own implementations. For all practical purposes, I think it is better to copy-paste.