# Could someone explain what purpose EventQueue object serves?

Tags: java, swing, events, awt, awt-eventqueue

Could someone explain what purpose `EventQueue` object serves in Java Swing?

I'm mostly confused about how queuing events is applied. Maybe providing common use of an event queue would be helpful.

Comment: *"..EventQueue object serves in Java Swing?"* Although Swing uses it, the `EventQueue` is from AWT.

Comment: I most cases, you don't interact with the `EventQueue`. The `EventQueue` is a queue of events, which is processed by the Event Dispatching Thread, these events are delivered to components and interested parties in order to provide notification of something happening, like a mouse click or key board event. The `EventQueue` provides a concept of "order" where events can only occur in a linear fashion, one after the other and generally within a time sequenced order (so my key stroke can't bet my mouse event if I moved the mouse first)

Answer (score 2):

Because Swing is [single threaded](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7158505/230513), it uses the [`EventQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html) to hold instances of `Runnable` so that they can be dispatched *sequentially* and in the *order posted*, whether generated by the system or your program. The *sine qua non* usage is posting an event via `EventQueue.invokeLater()`, which ensures that Swing GUI objects are constructed and manipulated *only* on the [event dispatch thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html). You can replace the AWT `EventQueue` with your own implementation, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3158409/230513), to see the events as they are placed in the queue.