# Some vagueness about EventQueue and Event Dispatching Thread

Tags: java, swing, awt

```
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        new MyJFrame().setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

I often see the above code snippet in Java Swing GUI applications. The `java.awt.EventQueue` seems to serve as **a global access point** for the message queue which is consumed by the `Event Dispatching Thread`.

My questions are:

- Is the sole purpose of `java.awt.EventQueue` to serve as a global communication channel between other threads and the EDT? Any other scenarios to use it?
- How/When is the EDT launched?

Comment: Question 1) is examined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36904354/230513); 2) happens when an event is posted to a non-running queue.